# склонение падежи согласование

Tags: согласование, склонение

Как правильно: был молодцом или был молодец? Какое здесь правило, в том числе в других подобных случаях, например с прилагательными? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбор варианта делается по контексту, при этом учитывается влияние разных факторов. К примеру, считается,  что  Т.п. в большей степени обозначает временной признак, а И.п. ― постоянный признак.

Это различие мы видим в следующих примерах:

1) **Оценка  характера как постоянного свойства**

Жило вообще **был молодец**. Даже с командиром дивизиона не боялся ссориться. [Олег Березовский. «Я подам в суд на Путина» (2004) // «Калининградские Новые колеса», 2004.11.11]

2) **Текущая оценка поведения в конкретной ситуации**

Один Иван **был молодцом.** Терпеливо ответил на все тетушкины вопросы, вежливо поинтересовался здоровьем и вежливо выслушал ее длиннющий отчет. [Борис Васильев. Были и небыли. Книга 1 (1988)]

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта допустимы.
Правила особого нет, просто сейчас вариант творительного падежа вытесняет именительный. 
Явление это сложное, варианты с переменным успехом долгое время конкурировали друг с другом.

Здесь, правда, есть еще один нюанс. "Был молодцом" означает ко всему прочему еще и сравнение (проявил себя молодцом). Вот тут именительный падеж нежелателен совсем.